# Is there a way to count a number of accesses to GCS (not a function calls) by analysing audit log in generated audit table in BigQ?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, audit-logging

I wonder if there is a way to count the actual number of accesses to a certain GCP service by analysing audit log stored in BigQ. In other words, I have audit tables sink to BigQ (no actual access to Stackdriver). I can see a number of rows were generated per single access, i.e. it was one physical access to the GCS, but about 10 rows generated due to different function calls. I'd like to be able to say how many attempts/accesses were made by the user account by looking at X number of rows. [This is a data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSalG.png).

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go read How to Ask. and stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the sink works well and the logs are being exported to BQ, then you would need to check the format on how audit logs are written to BQ and the fields that are exported/written to BQ [1].

Then filter the logs by resource_type and member, these documents [2][3] can help you with that.

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/understanding-audit-logs#sample

[2] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/understanding-audit-logs#sample

[3] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/understanding-audit-logs#interpreting_the_sample_audit_log_entry